# Using lambda expressions for summing up member variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like followings.

```
public class Votes{
    String name;
    int likes;
    int dislikes;

    //constructors, getters and setters    
}
```

I am having a list like followings.

```
List<Votes> votesList;
```

Assume I am populating above list with some elements. I want to declare a method which performs grouping and summing operation in that list.

As an example, assume I am giving the following elements in a list as the `input` for that method.

```
votesList.add(new Votes("A", 10, 5));
votesList.add(new Votes("B", 15, 10));
votesList.add(new Votes("A", 20, 15));
votesList.add(new Votes("B", 10, 25));
votesList.add(new Votes("C", 10, 20));
votesList.add(new Votes("C", 0, 15));
```

That method should output a `List<Votes>` with the following elements.

```
("A", 30, 20),
("B", 25, 35),
("C", 10, 35)
```

Is there an easy way to do that using streams, lambda expressions in Java8? I know how it can be done using `collectors` if I only have one `int` memeber.

Can someone please explain me how can I address this situation?

Comment: You'll have to write your own collector. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I pretty much appreciate if you could elaborate as an answer. :))

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik could you please give a comment about my answer. :)) are there any ways to improve?

Comment: It's not a purely functional approach, but who cares if it works. And it's very simple code, a big advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I came across this as the easiest way. :))

```
Map<String, List<Votes>> grouped = voteCountList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r->r.getName()));

List<Votes> collectedList = new ArrayList<>();

grouped.forEach((groupName, votes) -> collectedList.add(new Votes(groupName,
                votes.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(r->r.getLikes())),
                votes.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(r->r.getDislikes())))));
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use `groupingBy`, combined with `reducing`:

```
Collection<Optional<Votes>> res =
     votesList.stream().collect(groupingBy(v -> v.name, reducing((v1, v2) -> new Votes(v1.name, v1.likes + v2.likes, v1.dislikes + v2.dislikes)))).values();
```

This will give you a `Collection<Optional<Votes>>`, you can get rid of it by combining the `reducing` collector and the finisher function `Optional::get` using the `collectingAndThen` collector but that will starts to look quite hard to read.

So another alternative could be to use `toMap`, and merge two votes whenever they have the same name:

```
Collection<Votes> res =
    votesList.stream().collect(toMap(v -> v.name,
                                     v -> v,
                                     (v1, v2) -> new Votes(v1.name, v1.likes + v2.likes, v1.dislikes + v2.dislikes))).values();
```

From there you can use the `ArrayList` copy-constructor (either by using `collectingAndThen` with  `m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())`, or by putting the previous expression in the parameter list of this copy constructor).

Comment: Hi, Thanx alot. can u pls check out my answer and give comments if any. :))

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started, it's not exactly what you want since it does not create the final list.

```
Map<String, Votes> collected = votesList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Votes::getName,
        collectingAndThen(reducing(
                (originalVotes, newVotes) -> new Votes(originalVotes.getName(), originalVotes.getLikes() + newVotes.getLikes(), originalVotes.getDislikes() + newVotes.getDislikes()))
                , Optional::get)));

collected.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println(key + "," + value.getLikes() + "," + value.getDislikes());
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx alot. can u pls check out my answer and give comments if any. :))

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a custom Collector.

Test code:

```
final List<Votes> votesList = new ArrayList<>();
votesList.add(new Votes("A", 10, 5));
votesList.add(new Votes("B", 15, 10));
votesList.add(new Votes("A", 20, 15));
votesList.add(new Votes("B", 10, 25));
votesList.add(new Votes("C", 10, 20));
votesList.add(new Votes("C", 0, 15));

final List<Votes> totals = votesList.stream().collect(new VoteCollector());
totals.forEach(votes -> {
    System.out.println(votes.getName() + "  " + votes.getLikes() + "  " + votes.getDislikes());
});
```

VoteCollector class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class VoteCollector implements Collector<Votes, Map<String, Votes>, List<Votes>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, Votes>> supplier() {
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, Votes>, Votes> accumulator() {
        return (map, votes) -> {
            final Votes mapVotes = map.get(votes.getName());
            if (mapVotes == null) {
                map.put(votes.getName(), new Votes(votes.getName(), votes.getLikes(), votes.getDislikes()));
            } else {
                mapVotes.setLikes(mapVotes.getLikes() + votes.getLikes());
                mapVotes.setDislikes(mapVotes.getDislikes() + votes.getDislikes());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, Votes>> combiner() {
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            for (final Entry<String, Votes> map2Entry : map2.entrySet()) {
                final Votes map1Votes = map1.get(map2Entry.getKey());
                if (map1Votes == null) {
                    map1.put(map2Entry.getKey(), map2Entry.getValue());
                }
                else {
                    map1Votes.setLikes(map1Votes.getLikes() + map2Entry.getValue().getLikes());
                    map1Votes.setDislikes(map1Votes.getDislikes() + map2Entry.getValue().getDislikes());
                }
            }

            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, Votes>, List<Votes>> finisher() {
        return map -> map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }   
}
```

The output is

```
A  30  20
B  25  35
C  10  35
```

[Here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/07/introduction-to-writing-custom.html) is one of many good sources for learning to write Collectors:

Comment: You can simplify the finisher to `map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())`. Further, you can use `Collector.of` to construct a `Collector` using the four funtions, without the need to create a new class implementing the `Collector` interface.

Comment: @Todd Hi, Thanx alot. can u pls check out my answer and give comments if any. :))